# How to use shadow

Tags: shadow

I am a Japanese university student. I decided to research Tor Browser graduation thesis. I've heard that I could use Shadow. However, I did not know how to use it. Could you tell me if there is a site that clearly explains how to use Shadow?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the shadow"? Where have you seen this phrase? Have you translated it from Japanese?

Comment: "Shadow" was found in the documentation of tor."Shadow" was to know that it is a tool for the simulation of the tor.However, there is no Japanese translation, I heard here because you do not know how to use.

Answer (score 2):

[Shadow](https://shadow.github.io/) is probably what you heard of. It has a [wiki](https://github.com/shadow/shadow/wiki/).